# ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 120, 1024, 1024)

Tags: python, keras, lstm, named-entity-recognition, elmo

I am trying for named entity recognition and here are the details of my x_train and x_test:
`Shape X_train: (3555, 120, 1024) Shape X_test: (887, 120, 1024)`

```
input = Input(shape=(120,))
word_embedding_size = 1024
model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=word_embedding_size, input_length=120)(input)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=word_embedding_size, 
                           return_sequences=True, 
                           dropout=0.5, 
                           recurrent_dropout=0.5, 
                           kernel_initializer=k.initializers.he_normal()))(model)
model = LSTM(units=word_embedding_size * 2, 
             return_sequences=True, 
             dropout=0.5, 
             recurrent_dropout=0.5, 
             kernel_initializer=k.initializers.he_normal())(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="relu"))(model)  # previously softmax output layer

crf = CRF(n_tags)  # CRF layer
out = crf(model)  # output
model = Model(input, out)

adam = k.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=crf.loss_function, metrics=[crf.accuracy, 'accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit(X_train , y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

The error is :
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional_14 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 120, 1024, 1024)`

This the `model.summary()`:
[image]

Please help me out, I am not able to solve it through other answers.

Comment: What is `n_words`?

Comment: n_words is size of the vocabulary in my text data. There are 44.283 vocab @ZWang

Comment: Can you post the model.summary?

Comment: i've edit my post @ZWang

Comment: The `Input` layer for the model has `shape=( 120 , )`. But you're providing `X_train` which has shape `( 3555 , 120 , 1024 )`, and hence the error.

Comment: so i should change it to `shape=( 3555 , 120 , 1024 )`?@ShubhamPanchal

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal i'm still get the same error. I don't understand. Help me please

Answer (score 0):

You must use Reshape layer after Bidirectional layer based on the output shape of the bidirectional layer

This might works:

```
model.add(Reshape((120, 2048), input_shape = (2048, )))
```